# Blinking screen on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04

I install linux ubuntu to notebook acer aspire v3. It have 2 video cards:integrated Intell and discrete NVIDIA GeForce 750M. After installing system screen start blinking (A few times per second, a black and normal screen changes). Aftert start opengltest glxgears blink disappears. After stopping the test, the blink appears again.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install the latest Nvidia drivers from the Nvidia web site, or the ones in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I install nvidia drivers from ubuntu repository

Comment: Those are the correct Nvidia drivers to install. You weren't clear in your question whether the problem occurs if you're using the Intel or Nvidia video card. Does the problem occur if you log into the Guest account?